@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) inserted ID is always 0
MyEntity
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
@ColumnInfo(name = "exploitsId")
var id: Long = 0
var name: String? = null


constructor(id: Long, name: String) {
    this.id = id
    this.name = name
}

constructor(name: String) {
    //this.id = null
    this.name = name
}

And when I insert data I get a lot of duplicate words "hello" with index 0
viewModel.insertTest(exploitsEnt("hello"))

Dao
@Dao
interface daoExploits {
@Query("SELECT * FROM exploitsEntTable")
fun getAllexploits(): LiveData<List<exploitsEnt>>


@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insertExploit(ExploitsEnt: exploitsEnt)

viewmodel
fun insertExploit(ExploitsEnt: exploitsEnt) {
    repository.insertExploit(ExploitsEnt)
}

How can I make sure that the index is generated automatically and is not constantly equal to 0?
Solved:
var id: Long? = null

Please [edit] your question and provide the full entity class as well as the DAO interface you use to insert the data.

Your issue is NOT that multiple or even any rows are being inserted where the value of the exploitsId column is 0. The issue is very likely to how your are handling the LiveData (observing).
using your code but adapted a little to suit running without using LiveData as per:-
@Entity(tableName = "exploitsEntTable")
class exploitsEnt {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "exploitsId")
    var id: Long = 0
    var name: String? = null

    constructor(id: Long, name: String) {
        this.id = id
        this.name = name
    }

    @Ignore /* ADDED will not compile without, msg in biuld will be:-
        error: Room cannot pick a constructor since multiple constructors are suitable.
        Try to annotate unwanted constructors with @Ignore.
    */
    constructor(name: String) {
        //this.id = null
        this.name = name
    }
}

@Dao
interface daoExploits {
        @Query("SELECT * FROM exploitsEntTable")
        /* LiveData commented out for demo (note .allowMainThreadQueries when building Room Database used so can use main thread) */
        fun getAllexploits(): /*LiveData<*/List<exploitsEnt>/*>*/


        @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
        fun insertExploit(ExploitsEnt: exploitsEnt)
}

As per the comments an @Database annotated class that using the .allowMainThreadQueries method:-
@Database(entities = [exploitsEnt::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun getTheDAOs(): daoExploits

    companion object {
        var instance: TheDatabase?=null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance==null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java,"the_database.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
    }
}

And finally some activity code to demonstrate:-
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: daoExploits
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getTheDAOs()

        for (i: Int in 1..10) {
            /* Use first constructor */
            dao.insertExploit(exploitsEnt(0,"Name${i}"))
            /* Use second constructor */
            dao.insertExploit(exploitsEnt("OtherName${i}"))
            /* 10th iteration will replace*/
            if (i > 9) {
                dao.insertExploit(exploitsEnt(i.toLong(), "Unique Conflict so replace Name${i} "))
            }
        }
        for (m in dao.getAllexploits()) {
            Log.d("DBINFO","ID is ${m.id} NAME is ${m.name}")
        }
    }
}

Running the above should (when first run) loop 10 times each time:-

Insert a row based upon an exploitsEnt where the id field is 0 and the name field is Name? (where ? is as per the value of i; i.e. 1, then 2, then 3 ....), then:-
Insert a second row based upon an exploitsEnt where the id field will default and the name field will be OtherName? (? as per i), then:-
IF i is greater than 9 then use the current value of i to set the id field and thus try to insert a row where exploitsId is 9. Due to the UNIQUE conflict and the REPLACE strategy, the row with explotsId being 9 will be replaced with the name field as Unique Conflict so replace Name? (? as per i).

The result (when first run) output to the log:-
2024-07-01 14:08:42.099 D/DBINFO: ID is 1 NAME is Name1
2024-07-01 14:08:42.099 D/DBINFO: ID is 2 NAME is OtherName1
2024-07-01 14:08:42.099 D/DBINFO: ID is 3 NAME is Name2
2024-07-01 14:08:42.099 D/DBINFO: ID is 4 NAME is OtherName2
2024-07-01 14:08:42.099 D/DBINFO: ID is 5 NAME is Name3
2024-07-01 14:08:42.100 D/DBINFO: ID is 6 NAME is OtherName3
2024-07-01 14:08:42.100 D/DBINFO: ID is 7 NAME is Name4
2024-07-01 14:08:42.100 D/DBINFO: ID is 8 NAME is OtherName4
2024-07-01 14:08:42.100 D/DBINFO: ID is 9 NAME is Name5
2024-07-01 14:08:42.100 D/DBINFO: ID is 10 NAME is Unique Conflict so replace Name10 
2024-07-01 14:08:42.100 D/DBINFO: ID is 11 NAME is Name6
2024-07-01 14:08:42.100 D/DBINFO: ID is 12 NAME is OtherName6
2024-07-01 14:08:42.100 D/DBINFO: ID is 13 NAME is Name7
2024-07-01 14:08:42.100 D/DBINFO: ID is 14 NAME is OtherName7
2024-07-01 14:08:42.100 D/DBINFO: ID is 15 NAME is Name8
2024-07-01 14:08:42.100 D/DBINFO: ID is 16 NAME is OtherName8
2024-07-01 14:08:42.100 D/DBINFO: ID is 17 NAME is Name9
2024-07-01 14:08:42.100 D/DBINFO: ID is 18 NAME is OtherName9
2024-07-01 14:08:42.100 D/DBINFO: ID is 19 NAME is Name10
2024-07-01 14:08:42.100 D/DBINFO: ID is 20 NAME is OtherName10

As can be seen the results are as expected and as originally stated there are no duplicated values in the exploitsId column, all the values bar 1 have clearly been generated from 1-20.
The exception as such is that on the 10th and last iteration the row that was 10 OtherName10 has been replaced and is 10 Unique Conflict so replace Name10.

Note if the above demo code were rerun then the results be another 20 with exploitsId being 21-40 but Name/OtherName being 1-10. Row 10 would again be replaced but with the same values.

You may wish to adopt the above "test run on the main thread" as a means of testing/splitting the two distinct areas.
